# How to find/filter state from react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im trying to find data from mapStateToProps with passing params to it.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
const categoryId = props.match.params.id;
return {
    category: state.categories.find((item) => item.id === categoryId)
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(categoryForm);
```

When I try (item.id === 1) I get the data of category, but when I try (item.id === categoryId) data of category is undefined. And I try to console categoryId, it's ok I get the id from params but why it's not working when I try like this (item.id === categoryId) ?

**categoryAction.js**

```
import api from '../api';
import { FETCH_CATEGORIES } from '../types';

export function setCategories(categories){
return {
    type: FETCH_CATEGORIES,
    categories
  }
}

export const fecthCategory = () => dispatch => 
    api.category.getCategories().then(categories => 
    dispatch(setCategories(categories)))
```

**categoryReducer.js**

```
import { FETCH_CATEGORIES } from '../types';

export default function categories(state = [], action ={}){
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_CATEGORIES:
        return action.categories;
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

**rootReducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import categories from './reducers/categoryReducer.js';

export default combineReducers({ 
     categories
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `categoryId` is a string and you're using strict equality `===` for comparison.
Try `state.categories.find((item) => item.id === Number(categoryId))`.
Hope that helps.